# Trying to validate sessionStorage token and replace the path - does not work in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to validate sessionStorage key and if valid then don't show register page and redirect to deashboard. But getting issue and it does not redirect or replce the path and show the register component again even user logged in.

Any help will be appriciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
//import $ from 'jquery';
import Home from './home';
import About from './about';
import Contact from './contactus';
import Register from './register';
import Deshboard from './Deshboard/deshboard';

class MenuBar extends Component
{
  requireAuth(nextState,replace)
      {
         var token = sessionStorage.getItem("authtoken_Session");   
         if(token != null)
         {
             replace({pathname: '/deshboard'});
         }
         else{
            replace({pathname: '/register'});
         }
     }

  render()
    {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App-header">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-4"></div>
                            <div className="col-md-6"></div>
                            <div className="col-md-1">
                                  <div className="myAccount"><Link to="/register">My Account</Link></div>                                  
                             </div>
                             <div className="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>  
                <div className="app-menu">                     
                                <ul className="clear-fix">
                                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link> </li>
                                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link> </li>
                                    <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link> </li>                                    
                                </ul> 
                        <div className="clear"> </div>
                    </div>
                <div className="body">
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>                    
                    <Route path="/register" component={Register} onEnter={this.requireAuth}/>
                    <Route path="/deshboard" component={Deshboard} onEnter={this.requireAuth}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    };
}

export default MenuBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onEnter has been deprecated and will not work. You need `render` prop or you can create your custom `PrivateRoute` which will perform authentication related  checks and then you can either redirect or render some other component.

Here is complete example from react-router-dom docs

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: Thank you @Zohaib Ijaz for the reply. Let me try that.